# Structuring and reusing React Styled-components and native components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, modularity

I’m a backend engineer who is learning frontend – very much a noob at this point. I’m currently learning React and came across styled-components¬, which seems like a great way of handling styling whilst using components.
I’m currently having issues using styled-components with native [React] components and changing them in a modular fashion. I can’t think of a viable option of doing what I want to do, or more likely, I’m doing it wrong.
Use case:
Here my folder setup:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFbny.png)

I’ve decided to include two files for each component:

- Styles: where all styled-component components reside.
- Component: which combines one or more styled-components into a reusable component.

Here the styles.js:

```
const StyledDeleteButton = styled.button`
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;

    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: green;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

Here the components.js:

```
const DeleteButton = () => <StyledDeleteButton>Delete</StyledDeleteButton>;
```

What I want to achieve:
In my styles, I don’t want to apply any positioning now - but can later via props of course. But I want to use the native component which has the Delete text. So, my question is, how can I apply addition styling on the component?

Inheriting the native component, but doesn't seem possible. I can apply what I want via CSS but want to be consistent as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to apply any styles for now and do it later, you can pass `className` as a prop like this, and just use the native `<button />` element

```
const DeleteButton = ({className}) => <button className={className}>Delete</button>;
```

Then later for adding styles, you have to use the `styled` function on the `DeleteButton` component

```
const StyledDeleteButton = styled(DeleteButton)`
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;

    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: green;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

[Styling any component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component) from the doc

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Worked a charm! Thanks